# Error Invoking Chaincode, Node SDK, Method: channel.sendTransactionProposal()

Tags: node.js, client, hyperledger-fabric

I am recieving a TypeError from the hyperledger fabric node sdk when I try to send a transaction proposal. Below is my calling code:

```
    const prop_response = await channel.sendTransactionProposal({
        targets: peers,
        chaincodeId: "ccid1",
        fcn: ADD_ASSET,
        args: [mockAsset],
        txId: client.newTransactionID()
    });
```

The documentation for the method can be found here: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html#sendTransactionProposal__anchor
The docs claim the method is expecting a ChaincodeInvokeRequest object however the code is not expecting an object. Below is the error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type object
    at Function.from (buffer.js:225:9)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the `args` property contains data that are not of type `string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object.`

Ensure that each argument of the array match the type required. Check if there is no `undefined` elements for example.

In your sample, I assume `mockAsset` is a json object. From my experience, you should stringify your json and then parse it back in your chaincode.

```
const prop_response = await channel.sendTransactionProposal({
        targets: peers,
        chaincodeId: "ccid1",
        fcn: ADD_ASSET,
        args: [JSON.stringify(mockAsset)],
        txId: client.newTransactionID()
    });
```

In your chaincode (programming model < 1.4):

```
mockAsset = JSON.parse(args[0])
```

programming model >= 1.4

```
mockAsset = JSON.parse(myParam)
```

For this answer to be complete, you should tell us what is `mockAsset`.